British/Irish and British citizen traveling into Schengen - which immigration queue
If two friends, one with both British and Irish citizenship (and traveling on the Irish passport), and the other only British, are visiting together the Schengen Area from the UK, which immigration counter should they use? They can't use the EU family union provisions. Can they both enter via the EU citizen queue, even though one isn't an EU citizen? Assume for this question that ETIAS is fully active.

There is no "non-EU" queue.  There is a queue for "EU/EEA/CH" and there is one for "All passports."  The person who is not also Irish must go to the "all passports" queue; the person who is also Irish can join the first person in that queue or go separately to the EU/EEA/CH queue.
In practice, some border posts will probably process them together in the EU/EEA/CH queue -- I've never been asked to prove family relationships of family members in that queue -- but others may send you back to the other queue.  I've never seen that in person, but I've seen reports here (even for a married couple, who had the right to use the EU/EEA/CH queue under the Schengen Borders Code).
If you don't have a reason to gamble on this, it's probably best not to try it.  If you're certainly going to miss a connection in the "all passports" queue but might make it if you use the EU/EEA/CH queue, by all means try it.  The worst that could happen would be that they send you back and you miss your flight.

If those two friends are not living in the same household they probably should use separate lines. The Irish citizen goes in the EU citizen queue and the UK citizen go to the All passports queue. However, if they have a reason to stay together, they can both use the All passports queue because it is for All passports, that's not exclusive for non-EU citizens.

They aren't in the same household. But they are traveling together. I thought that people who are traveling in a close group should approach the immigrate together, rather than separately

@CSM Different airports probably have different practices. If you let me know the relevant airport I can hopefully give you the email address to their immigration
